# In PHP, how to tell if pg_query() was a query that returns data?

Tags: php, postgresql

So a successful `mysqli_query()` returns true if there is no data and it returns a `mysqli_result` object if there is data(ie the query was a `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN`).

But with a successful `pg_query()` it always returns the samething(a query result resource) regardless of whether or not there's any data coming back.

Can I use the `pg_query()` return value to determine if the query was either `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE` or `EXPLAIN` like I can do with `mysqli_query()`?

Comment: Maybe `pg_num_rows()`? (sounds hackish though)

Comment: why do you need to know the kind of query that was executed? You should be able to provide that information to the piece of code receiving the result handle.

Answer (score 3):

there is no full proof way to determine 'select' vs 'insert / update' from pg extension functions. two function can be used but work only if some rows are returned or affected by the sql.

```
// update / insert / delete sql and affect some row 
pg_num_rows($res); // 0
pg_affected_rows($res); // n

// select return some result
pg_num_rows($res); // n
pg_affected_rows($res); // 0
```

Comment: This even more true when you know that with Pg you can do INSERT ... RETURNING that *will* return inserted rows.

Comment: BEWARE: Since Postgres 9.0 [pg_affected_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-affected-rows.php) returns the same value as pg_num_rows() if the statement was a SELECT. But at least pg_num_rows() still returns 0 for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.