# Displaying message when results have or have not been found in PHP PostgreSQL Query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I am trying to write a conditional statement which echo's the following messages :

```
if  {the query executed bring results from the database 
Process the query
echo 'Success' }

else {
If no results/ 0 results have been retrieved then
echo 'No results obtained'}
```

I am using PostgreSQL as my database. I am new to using PostgreSQL with PHP but so far I have managed to make my queries work. I am just confused on how I can do this and which part of the code this logic should be in. Is it before the query has been executed.

```
      <?php
// Connecting, selecting database
 $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=sser user=postgres     password=password")
or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());


$name = pg_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$name2 = pg_escape_string($_POST['name2']);


$query = " SELECT y.name, y.time, z.name, z.time
FROM 
(SELECT * FROM departure_times  WHERE name ='$name') as y,
(SELECT * FROM departure_times  WHERE name ='$name2') as z
WHERE y.tram_id = z.tram_id ";

$result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
echo "These are the following trams from '$name' to '$name2' ";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
  }
  echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);


// Closing connection
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: Literally the first example on the PGSQL basics page on PHP.net: http://php.net/manual/en/pgsql.examples-basic.php

Comment: @SébastienVercammen the given page does not show that for me...

Comment: @FirstOne It shows how `while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))` works. You don't need much more to turn that `while` into an `if`.

Comment: So basically I should be doing the following :

    if  {($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC))

execute the query
echo 'Success'

}

else {
 echo ' Failure'
}

Comment: @SébastienVercammen, the OP's code already fetch the data. Please, take another look at the question. The problem seems to be with the `check if there are any records and display a message accordingly`. That link doesn't even have an `if` xD

Comment: That's what I am trying to do. Exactly what @FirstOne has said

Comment: @FirstOne If OP's code can fetch data, it's trivial to check the returned value to see if there were any results. PHP.net hosts a doc page for every function, including documentation for return values. You should know this.

Comment: Is there any simple way I can do this @SébastienVercammen ? I have provided my source code

Comment: @A.Khan Have you read PHP.net's documentation for `pg_fetch_array`?

Comment: I have taken a look at the documentation for this. I understand that it returns an array, but I am guessing I need to the something like the following :

$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");
if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occurred.\n";
  exit;
}

$arr = pg_fetch_array($result, 0, PGSQL_NUM);
echo $arr[0] . " <- Row 1 Author\n";
echo $arr[1] . " <- Row 1 E-mail\n";

 @SébastienVercammen

Comment: @A.Khan, maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13508777/4577762) helps. I just don't know if that's the proper way of doing what you want.

Comment: That's completely something different. I tried replacing the while with If but that did not work either. This is quite hard than it seems @FirstOne

Comment: @A.Khan Check if query executed: `if($result !== false) { ... }`. Check if you have any results: `if($arr !== false) { ... }`. As a refresher, here's [PHP.net's guide on booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php). You should follow a PHP course to understand the basics if you want to make it easier for yourself.

Comment: I really dont see how I can implement a Boolean value. I still can't get to output an echo message saying 'No Results' @SébastienVercammen

Comment: @A.Khan I highly suggest following a PHP/SQL basics course. If you can't understand what I explained in my previous comments, I can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three situations to deal with:

1. The query fails due to some error condition.
2. The query succeeds and returns one or more rows of data.
3. The query runs successfully, but returns no data because none match the query conditions.

In the first instance, `pg_query()` returns the boolean value **`false`** into the variable `$result`; your `or die()` clause handles this. In the second and third cases, `$result` contains a result set resource which may or may not contain data, and you want to know whether it does or not.

The PHP API for PostgreSQL contains a handy function for just that purpose called [`pg_num_rows()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-num-rows.php). This function takes a result set as its argument and returns an int showing the number of rows in the result. So your code would look something like this:

```
$result = pg_query($query)
    or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
if (pg_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    echo "I found some data.";
}
else
{
    echo "I got nothin'.";
}
```

Replace the `echo` statements with your own logic.

Comment: This is something similar to what I was looking for. MySQL example uses something quite similar to this which is mysql_num_rows. Thanks a lot. Really helpful and clear @Darwin von Corax